# Is it possible to add a Lightning Web Component to a Visualforce Page in Salesforce Classic?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, salesforce-classic

My employer is planning a transition to Lightning Experience in the coming months, so I have been learning to develop LWCs and practicing with real projects. I am wondering if it is possible to add those components I have developed to a Visualforce page for use in our org before we roll out Lightning to our users. If so, what is best practice?

Answer (score 7):

yes, starting from Summer '19 it is possible to add LWC to VF page via lightning out. Read [documentation](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_lwc_vf.htm)

Adding a Lightning web component to a Visualforce page is a three-step process.

1. Add the Lightning Web Components for Visualforce JavaScript library to your Visualforce page using the `<apex:includeLightning/>` component.
2. Create and reference a standalone Aura app that declares your component dependencies.
3. Write a JavaScript function that creates the component on the page using `$Lightning.createComponent()`.

Use the `<namespace:camelCaseComponentName>` naming convention to reference a Lightning web component in a Visualforce page.

You can find some examples on google, for example [this one](https://www.paul-force.com/2019/04/24/use-lightning-web-components-in-visualforce-pages/) and [example from documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_visualforce)